# ArangoDB real execution query time

Tags: arangodb

Hi I have a question.

I am using Arango Web Interface and ArangoSh, I checked my query execution time, and result is below.

var q = db._query('...MY QUERY STATEMENT...')
q.getExtra()

```
{
  "stats" : {
    "writesExecuted" : 0,
    "writesIgnored" : 0,
    "scannedFull" : 24518,
    "scannedIndex" : 287631,
    "filtered" : 0,
    "httpRequests" : 0,
    "executionTime" : 6.2454559803
  },
  "warnings" : []
}
```

I wonder whether the exeutionTime meaning is find, generate result time, network and etc all time or not.
In mysql, execution time is seperated network time, How ArangoDB deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution time reported is the time the server spends for the actual query execution. It includes the time parsing the query, creating the execution plan, loading collections if not already loaded, retrieving data and creating the result set.
It does not include any network transfer time, and/or HTTP processing time.